# layout-large-land-hdpi error

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use inside res the folder

layout-large-land-hdpi

but the sdk gives me an error and does not compile.

layout-large-hdpi works!

As it says [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), it should work!

Comment: Hmmm there was a red "X" on the folder in Eclipse. Now I deleted the folder and recreated and the "X" has gone away... ufff, it seemes it was an Eclipse or plugin error... :(

Comment: this happens due to R file is not generated properly.

Comment: same here. just clean the project and it works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

//yes we can use either layou-large and layout-large-mdi and so..

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation



  Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320 

res/layout-small-ldpi
res/layout-small-land-ldpi

Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432)

res/layout-ldpi
res/layout-land-ldpi

Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480

res/layout-mdpi
res/layout-land-mdpi

Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480

res/layout-large-mdpi
res/layout-large-land-mdpi

High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854)

res/layout-hdpi
res/layout-land-hdpi

Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res)

res/layout-xlarge
res/layout-xlarge-land
```

Comment: These resouce qualifiers can be used in any combination as needed, the OPs one is valid according to the docs. If he needs this one, then that's the way it is. I don't see how this solves the problem/answers the question.

Comment: Check the link I posted, it explains this.