# How to handle View while changing orientation? And how to display previous orientation data in In new orientation , without recreating?

Tags: android

Hi dude I created different UI's for portrait mode and landscape, How can I load in run time.?
I mean while changing orientation re creating the Activity I don't want to recreate it , How can I get previous data and display it in changed orientation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8491012/1012284

Comment: is it possible reuse portrait UI for landscape without calling setContentView(...) again ?

Comment: for every movement of rotation  oncreate executing how to restrict it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your portrait UI in `res/layout` folder & landscape UI in `res/layout-land` folder. The file name must be same. Android system will handle the automatic switching of the layout at run time.

For more detail about this read the artical in android developer. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html