# Providing unique layout for specific resolution in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use specific xml-layouts based on screen resolution, **not size**. So, the first design is used for resolution <= 480x800, and the second - for resolution >= 480x800.

How is it done ?

update.

I've come up with

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    final int height = display.getHeight();
    final int width = display.getWidth();



    int leadingResolutionSize = Math.max(height, width);
    if(leadingResolutionSize <= 800){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }else if(leadingResolutionSize > 800 && leadingResolutionSize <= 1024){
        setContentView(R.layout.main_1024_600);
    }else if(leadingResolutionSize > 1024){
        setContentView(R.layout.main_1280_800);
    }
```

**Do you think it's a good solution ?**

Answer (score 1):

you can create different xml layouts

and put all them in

- hdpi
- idpi
- mdpi
- xhdpi

for more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491012/1289716) answer

Comment: It doesn't work for me(Android 2.3.3). What I have is /res/layout-hdpi, /res/layout-xhdpi, /res/layout-xlarge. For all three AVDs I created(480x800, 1024x600, 1280x800) I get layout from /res/layout-hdpi. Can you post a sample project ? Another thing I've found in above(magager) - is it worth trying ? It precisely figures out each resolution, so I can at least "if" between the layouts

Answer (score 0):

`layout` folder in your project contains xml files which can be designed defaultly for `PORTRAIT` Mode(that is 480*800 in your case). If you want for `LANDSCAPE` Mode.In the same way declare another folder named as `layout-land`(that is 800*480) and store the layout xml files in that folder and modify those files based on your requirement.