# Uploading Multiple apk of same android app

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an app which has 5 or 4 different projects in eclipse. My one apk contains configuration of xlarge mdpi, large hdpi and normal hdpi. Other has normal xhdpi. Now i have to make seperate APK for google nexus s and Samsung S3 for some reason. But both have the same configuration i.e normal-xhdpi-1280x720. How can i upload them to google play using  multiple apk support ? what can i add to my manifest for these and how would the respected apk be available to the respective device?
Note that all of these uses build version 2.2. And i want to configure them on the basis of screen size and density.

Comment: 1 apk is enough to support all devices.

Comment: i have different layouts and asset files for nexus s and samsung s3 how can i make them in one apk ? since both of there folder names are same i.e layout-normal-xhdpi-1280x720 ??

Comment: if both are same why you want different layouts?

Comment: you are not getting my point ! anyways i got the solution

Comment: is this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/8491012/1012284

Comment: for google nexus i named the folder layout-normal-xhdpi and for samsung S3 i named it layout-normal-xhdpi-1280x720